# choice for camera sensor to be used with LiDAR

Tags: computer-vision

I am doing research on autonomous car and looking for a sensor to be used along with LiDAR laser scanner. Ladybug could be a very good option but the cost!! too expensive. 
Could you please suggest me options for camera sensors with good FOV and which will cost me around $1000. 
Thank you so much!!

-CHIANG CHEN

Comment: I voted to close this question because you want "camera sensors" with a "good" field of view, that cost around 1000 dollars. You need to define whether you want one camera at that price or if you are looking for multiple (stereo?) cameras, if you need a way to sync the cameras, what resolution you want, what fields of view are acceptable for you, and any other options you want. Once you define everything, Google is probably the place to ask.